# Get the name of the current invoking method at runtime

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to get the name of the current method in Groovy code?

```
def myMethod() {
   // want to get the string myMethod here
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tim_yates gives you a link to general solution.

This is shorter way to get method name. May be optimized, leawed as is for the sake of clarity.

```
class A {
    def myMethod() {
        for (m in new Throwable().stackTrace) {
            if (m.className == this.class.name)
                return m.methodName
        }
    }
}
println new A().myMethod()
```